# Spring bean factory with optional HTTP request

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I want to create a Spring bean which might depend on the HTTP request. Here's the code:

```
@Bean
@Scope(scopeName = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public MyBean getMyBean(Optional<HttpServletRequest> request) {
    if(request.isPresent()){
        return new MyBean(request);
    } else {
        return new MyBean();
    }
}
```

The problem is, Spring throws "No thread-bound request found" when there's no request available (for example when it wants to inject it to a Quartz triggered Job).

I've also tried writing something like

```
public MyBean getMyBean(ApplicationContext ctx){
```

But I haven't found a way to get the HTTP request from the `ApplicationContext`.

Is there any way to have a factory which will work when there's no request but will inject the request if one is available?

Comment: Why do you need a HttpServletRequest in a Job if this job is not stater by a real http invocation?

Comment: Because the bean is injected to a service which can be accessed both from a job and from a http invocation. If it's from a http invocation it will need to have a look at the request and get some information from it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the way invoke the service. It doesn't need a HttpRequest, instead you need to pass the data you really need.

At the moment you create your job, you need to store the data that you to pass to the service, if your job is create from an Http Invocation then you need to take the data from the Http Request in the moment you create the Job.

Comment: The problem is it needs values from the current request when it handles a web invocation and it relies on defaults when used from a job. A simple scenario would be a service which needs the clients IP. It wants the `request.getRemoteAddr()` to get the clients address when its called via the web and uses "127.0.0.1" when it's called by a job.

Comment: Yes, but the HttpRequest is part of a web request, so in order to get the web request you need that a web client make the invocation to the server. Your job is not a web request so you don't have a HttpRequest object. If you need the IP address to run your service you can get the IP from your Job and send it to the service and if the invocation is from the web you get the IP address from the HttpRequest object. In case the Job data is gotten from web request you can get first the client Ip address and store it and when the job is triggered you can access that Ip assdress.